# How to create a Legend with Points. Same size in Legend and Map. Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, javascript, legend, mapping

I am trying to create a Legend in Leaflet that contains the circles in the map.
But, the size in the legend should the same size that it is in the map.

My code is next.

```
function getRadius(pop) {
  var maxSymbolsize = 20; // maximum symbol size
  var maxValue = 37393129; // highest population value in the dataset
  r = maxSymbolsize * Math.sqrt(pop/maxValue); // proportional by area
  return r;
}

function getColor(d) {
return d > 10000000  ? '#d7301f' :
       d > 5000000   ? '#fc8d59' :
       d > 1000000   ? '#fdcc8a' :
                       '#fef0d9' ;
}


var legendcolor = L.control({position: 'bottomright'});
 legendcolor.onAdd = function (map) {
    var div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info legend'),
        grades = [0, 1000000, 5000000, 10000000],
        labels = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
        div.innerHTML +=
        '<i class ="circle" style="background:' + getColor(grades[i] + 1) + '"></i> ' +
        grades[i] + (grades[i + 1] ? '&ndash;' + grades[i + 1] + '<br>' : '+');
          }    return div;
   };
  legendcolor.addTo(map);
```

So, it gives me as a result:
[image]

As you see, it has circles but I want the sizes both the same in legend and map.

Here you see the CSS if can be involved in the solution. Where can I include the function `GetRadius` to make possible in legend.

```
.legend .circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  margin-top: 8px;
}
```

Comment: This is not really a GIS question but pure HTML. One possible solution is to have as many circle styles as there are grade ranges in the legend and then in the legend creation associate each grade range with corresponding style.

Answer (score 0):

It is too late now but, you need to get the size form the function as well just like you are doing for color:

```
 legendcolor.onAdd = function (map) {
    var div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info legend'),
        grades = [0, 1000000, 5000000, 10000000],
        labels = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
        div.innerHTML +=

      '<i class ="circle" style="border-radius: 50%; width:' + getRadius(grades[i] + 1) +'px; height:' + getRadius(grades[i] + 1) +'px; background:' + getColor(grades[i] + 1) +';"></i> ' +
        grades[i] + (grades[i + 1] ? '&ndash;' + grades[i + 1] + '<br>' : '+');
          } 
          return div;
   };
  legendcolor.addTo(map);
```